# how to read value from a session object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Using sql server stored procedure in Linq I m storing a list of questions in a session object as below.

```
DataClassesDataContext myContext = new DataClassesDataContext();
var QuestionList = myContext.sp_GetAllQuestions().ToList();
Session["QuestionsList"] = QuestionList;
```

How can I read or cast the value from this session object like

```
var QuestionList= Session["QuestionsList"]
```

Sql stored procedure looks like this

```
SELECT top 24 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QuestionID) AS QuestionNo,Q.QuestionID,Q.Question,Q.Choices,Q.CorrectAnswer,
 Q.RelatedInfo,Q.QuestionType,CS.Section FROM Questions Q left join dbo.ChapterSection CS on Q.SectionID=CS.SectionID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the usage of `var` to infer the type bites you.

Explicitly state the type of `QuestionList`, like this:

```
List<sp_GetAllQuestionsResult> QuestionList = = myContext.sp_GetAllQuestions().ToList();
Session["QuestionsList"] = QuestionList;
```

Now it is obvious when you get the value out of `Session` what you need to cast it to, like this:

```
List<sp_GetAllQuestionsResult> QuestionList= Session["QuestionsList"] as List<sp_GetAllQuestionsResult>;

// Check if the list is null or not
if(QuestionList != null)
{
    // Safe to use list because it was found and successfully cast

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of the week typed session because of the need to type cast each use, so I wrap all my types/objects in a strongly typed session wrapper.

Wrapper Base:

```
public abstract class SessionBase<T> : SessionBase where T : new()
{
    private static readonly Object _padlock = new Object();

    private static string Key
    {
        get { return typeof(SessionBase<T>).FullName; }
    }

    public static T Current
    {
        get
        {
            var instance = HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] as T;

            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (SessionBase<T>._padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] = instance = new T();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public static void Clear()
    {
        var instance = HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] as T;
        if (instance != null)
        {
            lock (SessionBase<T>._padlock)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now create an object (marking it as serializable helps)

```
[Serializable]
public QuestionCollection
{
  public QuestionCollection()
  {
    this.Questions = new List<Question>();
  }

  public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Now make the QuestionCollection strong typed QuestionCollectionSession

```
public QuestionCollectionSession : SessionBase<QuestionCollection>
{
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
QuestionCollectionSession.Current.Questions.Add("Are you there?");
```

When you want to clear/remove it from session:

```
QuestionCollectionSession.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Question> QuestionList= Session["QuestionsList"] as List<Question>;
List<Question> QuestionList= (List<Question>) Session["QuestionsList"];
```

You have to have the same type of objects to be able to cast and it has to be serializable.

The first one will give you null if it can't convert and the 2nd option will crash.

Comment: I have tried that already but getting an exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[sp_GetAllQuestionsResult]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Questions]'."

Comment: That means your types are not the same. The object you save has to be the same type when you're trying to read it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about storing and retrieving in same object type but is there any fix for this situation

Comment: You can map the stored object to other type

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what type your `QuestionsList` represents, but if you assume `QuestionList` is a `List<Question>` then you'd want something like:

```
var QuestionList= Session["QuestionsList"] as List<Question>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
News newsList=new News();

Session["news"]=newsList;
```

when you wanna get session object;

```
News newList=Session["news"] as News;
```

You have to cast session .Use like that